# Remove Bootstrap from from Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a web page in Asp.net Core MVC (dotnet 2.2) with authentication, and I want to replace Bootstrap with SemanticUI. I managed to do it on everything but Identity.

Or is there a way to build in user management but with custom written sites? (with Identity pages disabled).

I have changed layout for Identity, but there are still some bootstrap things and I dont know where are they from.

Page source:

```html
<div class="row"> <!--Why is this here?-->
   <div class="col-md-3"> <!--Why is this here?-->
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="four wide column">
         <div class="ui vertical tabular menu">
           <a class="item teal active" id="profile" href="/Identity/Account/Manage">Profile</a>
           <a class="item" id="change-password" href="/Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword">Password</a>
           <a class="item" id="two-factor" href="/Identity/Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication">Two-factor authentication</a>
           <a class="item" id="personal-data" href="/Identity/Account/Manage/PersonalData">Personal data</a>¨
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Layout that is set in Identity:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui inverted header">
        <div class="ui inverted stackable menu">
            <div class="ui container">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="~/spacex2.png" style="width: 15em">
                </div>
                <a class="item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Domů</a>
                <a class="item">Projekty</a>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui container">
            <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div class="ui inverted vertical footer segment" id="footer">
            <div class="ui container">
                <div class="ui stackable inverted divided equal height stackable grid">
                    <div class="three wide column">
                        <h4 class="ui inverted header">About</h4>
                        <div class="ui inverted link list">
                            <a href="#" class="item">Sitemap</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Contact Us</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Religious Ceremonies</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Gazebo Plans</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="three wide column">
                        <h4 class="ui inverted header">Services</h4>
                        <div class="ui inverted link list">
                            <a href="#" class="item">Banana Pre-Order</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">DNA FAQ</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">How To Access</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Favorite X-Men</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="seven wide column">
                        <h4 class="ui inverted header">Footer Header</h4>
                        <p>Extra space for a call to action inside the footer that could help re-engage users.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? You can't rewrite HTML, Identity is not working with changed layout...?

Comment: It is working, but I cant change layout, i guess there is something hidden that isn´t scaffolded with identity

Comment: There's a [`Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml) file that you haven't updated.

Comment: @LukášTrkan Can you provide picture with how it looks now and how it should look like? It's hard to answer when we don't know what the final result should look like.